# Get items from HTML list using VB.net

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

I need to get items from a html list from the vb.net code behind in my asp.net web site. Any thoughts on how this can be done? I want to use the list items then in an sql statement to retrieve data from a database.

Im using javascript on the front end to handle drag and drop between these two lists:

```
<div class="demo">
<table>
<tr>
    <td valign="top"> <ul id="All" class="connectedSortable sortable" style="border:groove" >
      <input name="DEMO" type="text" style="border:hidden; display:table-cell;" value="All Products" />
        <li class="ui-state-default">item1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">item2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">item3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">item4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">item5</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">item6</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">item7</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">item8</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">item9</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td valign="top"><ul id="Selected" class="connectedSortable sortable" style="border:groove">
      <input name="DEMO" type="text" style="border:hidden; display:table-cell;" value="Selected Products" />
      </ul></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I cannot use the runat="server" option as it removes the javascript drag and drop functionality on the main page.
Any help appreciated

Comment: An <input> element shouldn't be nested in a <ul>. Maybe that interferes with it. Unlikely, but you might as well use valid HTML markup to give it a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am curious about the requirement - if this is text that you have put on the page, cannot you retrieve it from the same location in your code behind?

Anyhow, to answer the question:

You can add the same items with some delimiter to a hidden textbox and read the value of that textbox in your code behind using the delimiter to separate the items.

Comment: i think using javascript and storing in hidden field does the trick thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question in not exactly clear for me.
But if you talking about retrieving value of `li` from code behind...

you have to use `runat="server"` on your list

```
eg. <li ID="myList" runat="server">My List Item</li>
```

Comment: if i put the runat="server" in the drag and drop javascript functionality does not work. I just want the item names in the selected list so i can then convert the names to string format and use in an sql query

Comment: if you need to access the elements from code behind, you have to use the **runat = "server"**

Answer (score 1):

1. Make your [`UL`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) `runat=server`, then you can access it in codebehind as `HtmlGenericControl` and get all items(as `LiteralControl`) with it's `Controls`-property.
2. Use a [`BulletedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.aspx) server control which has a [`Items` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items.aspx) and will be rendered as an unordered(ul) or ordered(ol) html-list.